# How to keep TinyMCE after postback in an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce

When I click a button that causes a postback on the `UpdatePanel` it calls the `tinyMCE.triggerSave()`.

It reloads the panel and the editor show up again, but when I try to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` the second time I get the following error:

```
g.win.document is null
```

I though it was getting the old instance, but I'm also removing the control (`tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'Editor');`) after I call the save. Even so it still crashes the second time.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699615/cant-post-twice-from-the-same-ajax-tinymce-textarea and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547327/how-to-make-tinymce-work-inside-an-updatepanel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much confusion I discovered that the fix which [@André Gadonski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522198/696638) posted no longer works in TinyMCE version 4. Not only does it not work, it provides no error feedback to the console!

The new command is `mceRemoveEditor`

Source: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31256

I found that this can either be used directly before re-initalising TinyMCE or just before the ASP update panel is refreshed using;

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'EditorID');
}
```

Comment: This! remember to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` before doing this otherwise you'll lose anything entered into the editor.

Comment: I am stuck for like 3 hours into this issue, have you written the above code  in `$(document).ready({..})` function?

Answer (score 6):

tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'Editor');

Before leaving the UpdatePanel, it will force tinyMCE to remove completely and then when you add again it won't crash.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This has been driving me insane!  Thank you so much!  Been googling this for over 90 minutes now.

Answer (score 3):

For tinymce 3.2.x, use the following to remove tinyMCE instance in IE8 or any other browser. As tinymce.execCommand function makes input fields uneditable in IE8.

```
tinyMCE.remove(editor); //editor is instance of tinymce editor and not editor id
```

This will fix "Permission Denied" error without disabling other input fields in the same page.

Answer (score 3):

i have same problem.for fix it you mast add script code for element create post back . my button create post back,I add it OnClientClick() :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbnSave" OnClick="lbnSave_Click" ToolTip="Add New" OnClientClick="dotim()"
                        runat="server">save</asp:LinkButton>
```

and script is:

```
function dotim() {
   tinyMCE.triggerSave();
  } // this is my attempt at a fix
```

Answer (score 1):

### It was so helpful for me.

I was using tinymce in angular 2. But when I was redirected the tinymce was disappeared.
I guess it's because of reusing tinymce.
So I removed the tinymce before using.

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'templateEditor');
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#templateEditor',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['autoresize']
  });
```

Thank you.